# What are some GIS outlets for my open source MapBasic utility module and library?

Tags: c#, mapinfo, .net, mapbasic, windows

I'm actively developing a MapBasic module that provides additional MBX programming functionality by wrapping .NET 4.0 and Win32 API calls in easy to use MapBasic functions and subs.  MB_Utils acts as an abstraction layer so a user can easily do things that are not directly supported in MapBasic: get Windows user name, display custom progress bars and dialogs, perform file i/o, etc.  I've sort of been filling in the frustrating shortcomings of MapBasic I've come across.

I'm looking fro some suggestions on where to post MB_Utils so as to gain exposure to other MapBasic developers.  MB_Utils is hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/mfcallahan/MB_Utils

https://github.com/mfcallahan/MB_Utils/releases

Comment: +1 for looking for ways to share custom tools with other users

Comment: I realize there is a very limited audience for MapInfo/MapBasic development, but in addition to GitHub and here, I've also made MB_Utils available on the [MapInfo-L](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mapinfo-l) discussion board, and at [communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/](http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/).  I'm trying to cast a wide net so my project may pop up in a google search result of any other MB developers out there whose development needs could be met with my library.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your module.

You have mentioned a number of places yourself so let's try to summarize:

- communitydownloads.pbinsight.com: The Pitney Bowes Software site for sharing tools and source code for all our products
- MapInfo-L on Google Groups: the mailing list for a questions related to MapInfo products. It has been around for two decades and it quite active.
- mapinfotools.com: a site for sharing tools with or without source code
- directionsmag.com: on their resource site you can find a bunch of stuff related to GIS tools, including MapInfo tools with and without source code